# How to verify if the value already exist. PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, forms, stored-procedures

Im having trouble in the stored procedure in MSSQLServer is this the right syntax for verifying value that is already existing?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SRP_DuplicateData]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@BankName nvarchar(50),
@BankCode nvarchar(5)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT BankName, BankCode FROM ZREF_ROUT_INCO_DOC where BankName=@BankName 
and BankCode=@BankCode

END
```

This is my php code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['SUBMIT']))
    {
       $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, "EXEC sp_SRP_DuplicateData(?,?)");

    if(sqlsrv_num_rows($query)>0)
    {
      echo "Bank Name or Bank Code already exist";
    }

  }

  ?>
```

This is the form

```
    <label class="form-top">Add Bank</label>
    <div class="form-group">
    <form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: left;">  

            <b>Bank Name:</b><input type="text" name="BankName" value="" 
id="" class="" /><br>
            <b>Bank Abbreviation: </b><input type="text" name="BankCode" 
value="" id="" class="" /> <br>
            <input type="SUBMIT" name="SUBMIT" value="Proceed" id="Bank" 
class="btn btn-lg btn-default" />
```

Comment: There is no Javascript in this question. Please tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: Also, this is not related to Bootstrap.

Comment: Okay I'm so sorry for that.

Comment: This seems related to forms and inputs; we'd need to see that to make sure everything is ok in there. Maybe the submit is not firing. If it is, let me know so I can delete this comment. @arusocse

Comment: @DaleBurrell Im having trouble with my php code also. I think the problem is in the php code. After I removed the single quotation there is no progress at all. Still not functioning. No error message to display. And still redirecting to the next modal.

Comment: What happens when you run the SP in SSMS? (Please also remove the quotes from your question as they are definitely wrong).

Comment: Command(s) completed successfully. Even if there is a single quote or not

Comment: That implies that there are no matching records.

Comment: Hmm... how are you passing the parameters to the procedure? I believe you need to pass an array of them http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php But the query should work in SSMS if you pass in the correct parameters.

Comment: I added (?,?) beside the Stored Procedure in the php code. I Already edited it in my question. 2 Question marks because i have 2 parameters needed to supply value

Comment: But you have have to pass the values from the form as a third parameter.

Comment: I think I get it. Do I need to set my values to the textfield? Do I need to echo it in values?

Comment: Dunno - you're right, thats PHP. However I'm curious as to why the SP doesn't work in SSMS.

Comment: Here is the problem. Must declare the scalar variable "@BankName".

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass your values to the stored procedure, you need to provide an array of the values to the sqlsrv_query function...

```
$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, "EXEC sp_SRP_DuplicateData(?,?)", array( $_POST['BankName'], $_POST['BankCode'] ));
```

The Stored Procedure you have posted looks ok to me, however you have SET NOCOUNT ON which I believe will not return the count of rows required by the sqlsrv_num_rows function. You should use the sqlsrv_has_rows function for the test of rows...

```
if(sqlsrv_has_rows($query))
{
  echo "Bank Name or Bank Code already exist";
}
```